# Ruby on rails Layout page blinking on link clicks in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a site-wide header I'm currently using in my layouts/application.html.erb file and when I click on links to go from page to page within the website, all of the web content (including the header) in the Chrome browser blinks looking like it is doing a full page load.  In Firefox there is no blink for the header content when I go from page to page within the website.  Do RoR layout/application.html.erb pages produce a full page refresh?  Is this a browser bug?

Version Info:
Firefox Version 3.0.1
Chrome Version 13.0.782.220
Ruby on Rails 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, clicking a link will do a full page refresh in Rails by default. This is standard behavior across all websites and browsers. Firefox and Chrome are both refreshing the entire page. The difference you notice is purely aesthetic. If you want something different, then consider looking into jQuery with asynchronous ajax requests.